# Returning a value in a function under a decorator in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am struggling to wrap my head around decorators in Flask.

I am using an external libarary named Yfrake which works by using @class.session decorator and a function under it. The function works if it set above app = Flask(**name**), but I can only print the values in the function, but when trying to return the value it returns None.

My code is:

```
@client.session
def main(user_input):
    final_list=[]
    stock_list=[]
    stock_list.append(user_input)
    queries=[]
    for i in stock_list:
        queries.append(dict(endpoint='price_overview', symbol=i))
    results = client.batch_get(queries)
    for resp in results.gather():
        final_list.append(resp.data["regularMarketPrice"]["raw"])
    return final_list[0]
```

Never mind that I am returning the firat value from the list, it's just for testing.

So why excatly I can print the final_list[0] but not return it as a value? How can I make it work?

Comment: how do you call it ? Is that a route of your server ?

Comment: Oh, I call the function by simply using main()

Comment: Why do you use flask so ? Flask is to make a server and call it using URLs, not executing it's call by hand

Comment: I am running a website server using flask, the yfrake library is working by using "@class.session", as seen above, and I want to use it for several reasons. So if I want to use yfrake to gather stock data I'll need to call the function above, and it's have to be under the "@class.session". Maybe Flask reads this as URL route and therefor returning None? Is there a way around it?